# Node.js form-data posted to symfony endpoint is NULL

Tags: node.js, symfony, post, null, request

A few days ago I found that posting data with "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" won't let me send characters such as ñ, ç, á, é, í, ó, ú and other non-ASCII used in some languages.
It returned [ERR_INVALID_CHAR].

Googling a little bit, I found that in order to post big amounts of data and non-ASCII characters, I should be using "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data" (a form, basically).

So, since the info I'm posting is not collected in a Template Form, I had to build the form-data object directly in a function in my node.js server application.
Here is my node.js code:

```
const formData = require('form-data');
const https = require('https');

const form = new formData();
form.append('name', 'ñámeç');

let options = {
    hostname: 'dev.mydomain.com',
    path: '/processdata',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: form.getHeaders()
}

let req = https.request(options, res=>{
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log(''+chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', function(){
        console.log('end');
    });
});

req.on('error',function(e){
    console.log(e);
})

form.pipe(req);
```

Then, the API in dev.mydomain.com/processdata is built in Symfony5.
Prior to my change from "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data", the code was:

```
public function processdata(Request $request)
{
    // Get post data
    $json = $request->get('json', null);
    // Json decode data
    $guest = json_decode($json);

    ... DO SOME STUFF ...

    $data = "RESULTING STRING";

    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```

I have changed it to:

```
public function processData(Request $request)
{
    // This is how I expected it would be:
    var_dump($request->request->get('name'));

    // This is just in case it was arriving as GET instead of POST (yes, I'm desperate):
    var_dump($request->query->get('name'));

    //  This is just in case it was arriving as a form object.
    var_dump($request->query->get('form')['name']);

    // This is also a desperate test, but I found some forums pointing this out: 
    var_dump($request->get('name'));

    // Trying to print the request contents:
    print_r($request->request);

    // Since all the $request calls in the var_dumps returned NULL or EMPTY data, I forced the enpoint to return a string to make sure I had a response.

    // Forcing a string for the callback:
    $data = "FORCED RESULTING STRING";

    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```

Then I run my node.js application and outputs are:

```
Claire:Test claire$ node test.js
200
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object
(
    [parameters:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
"FORCED RESULTING STRING"
end
```

May anyone, please, save me?
I've been stuck here for a couple of days.
All I could read also here in stackoverflow doesn't apply to my case or I'm just not realising the difference.

If I'm missing any data you might need me to clarify, please, let me know.

Thanks a lot in advance, and I hope you all are safe and healthy.

Comment: Hi, could you edit your question with a dump of `$request` object. Also are you sure that `form.pipe(req);` add the data to the request?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, @qdequippe!!
I wasn't sure, but you lit up my path!

I have checked again the [form-data npm docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) and, apparently, `form.getHeaders()` will only set the multipart/form-data headers.

I remembered that Symfony requires Content-Length header to be set. Otherwise, posted data goes NULL.

Then, I have tried to use form.submit() again (I did before but apparently I didn't do it right) and it sets Content-Length for me. The magic is done:

```
const formData = require('form-data');
const https = require('https');

const form = new formData();
form.append('name', 'ñámeç');

form.submit('https://dev.mydomain.com/processdata', function(err,res){

    console.log(res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log(''+chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', function(){
        console.log('end');
    });
    res.resume();
});
```

And it returns:

```
Claire:Test claire$ node test.js
200
string(8) "ñámeç"
NULL
NULL
string(8) "ñámeç"
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag Object
(
    [parameters:protected] => Array
        (
            [name] => ñámeç
        )

)
"FORCED RESULTING STRING"
end
```

$request->request->get('name') catches the "name" post field now.

I'm not sure how to proceed now. Should I mark my reply as valid? Maybe you could create a reply so I can mark yours, @qdequippe!!! THANKS A LOT!
Have a nice day!